# A confusion on Lettuce "Command flushing"

Tags: lettuce

In Lettuce Wiki, [Command flushing](https://github.com/lettuce-io/lettuce-core/wiki/Pipelining-and-command-flushing#command-flushing) section, it says that

> Command flushing is an advanced topic and in most cases (i.e. unless your use-case is a single-threaded mass import application) you won’t need it **as Lettuce uses pipelining by default**.

**The normal operation mode of Lettuce is to flush every command** which means, that every command is written to the transport after it was issued.

**Q1**: The above two statements are conflict with each other. The first paragraph says pipeline is the default behavior, but the second says flush every command is the normal mode.

---

**Q2**: Why **AutoFlushCommands** can not set on pooled connection?

> The **AutoFlushCommands** state is set per connection and therefore affects all threads using the shared connection. If you want to omit this effect, use dedicated connections. **The AutoFlushCommands state cannot be set on pooled connections by the Lettuce connection pooling**.

I guess a simple example might be looks like this (pseudo code)

```
conn = pool.get_connection()  # borrow a connection from pool
conn.set_auto_flush_commands(false)

conn.set(xxx, xx)
conn.set(yyy, yy)
conn.flush_commands()  # send commands to redis
conn.close()  # or return
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll leave question 2 to someone else, but I can talk to question 1.

I'll only talk about async since sync doesn't work without auto-flush.

With auto-flush enabled, lettuce will write out each request to Redis individually as it's made. This means if you make 100 requests, lettuce will send 100 TCP packets over the network, each with 1 request to Redis (you can see this with Wireshark).

With the async commands you can still send all 100 requests before reading any of them (which is pipelining), but you're still sending 100 individual requests.

With auto-flush disabled, you would queue those 100 requests in memory and then when you flush the buffer the commands are sent together, in as few TCP packets as possible. Disabling auto-flush yields better performance because you're reducing the number of expensive operations you perform.

Namely:

1. The number of times you're switching into the kernel to write to the network.
2. The overhead of individual TCP packets.
3. How much data is available for Redis to read from the socket at once.